# Redux-saga - selecting/waiting for data from multiple other sagas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm looking for a better pattern of selecting & waiting for data from several other sagas.

**Challenges:**

- loading data from multiple sources
- loaded data needs to be available to many different parts of the app
- asynchronous indeterminate flow of data loading

Here's my current implementation for loading data sources for use in a my saga:

```
/** For the purposes of this question:
  * getData returns a selector function (returns a portion of the state)
  * fetchData & setData are actionCreators (returns an action)
*/

function* doSomethingSaga() {
  let foo = yield select(getData('foo'));
  if (!foo.data) {
    if (!foo.loading && !foo.error) {
      yield put(fetchData('foo'));
    }
    foo = yield take('FOO_FETCHING_COMPLETE');
  }

  let bar = yield select(getData('bar'));
  if (!bar.data) {
    if (!bar.loading && !bar.error) {
      yield put(fetchData('bar'));
    }
    bar = yield take('BAR_FETCHING_COMPLETE');
  }

  const fooBar = doSomething(foo.data, bar.data);
  yield put(setData('fooBar', fooBar));
}

export default function* onDoSomething() {
  yield takeEvery('DO_SOMETHING', doSomethingSaga);
}
```

...there has to be a better way then adding 7 lines of code for each piece of data I need to load into a saga, but I've been unable to find it yet.